# How can I cut out text from a plane in indesign while preserving text edit?

Tags: adobe-indesign

Perhaps I'm in lack of correct search words, but here is what I need to do:

In indesign, I have a plane as background (lets say it is yellow).

I have a plane above that is blue.

Now, I want to cut out text from the blue plane, so that the text becomes yellow. But I want to preserve it as text. I know I can transform it and subtract it with pathfinder. Thats destructive.

In other words: the text should be the transparent part of the plane beneath. I this somehow possible?

Comment: Hi. What do you mean by "a plane"?  Can you show a screenshot perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is obviously a reason why you cannot simply have yellow text -  maybe the actual background is something more complex than an yellow rectangle.

So, here we have an yellow background rectangle, a blue rectangle above it and on the top there's some black text - all 100% opaque and with normal blending mode:

[image]

You can convert easily the text to holes:

[image]

The steps:

- turn the text fully transparent
- group the text frame and the blue rectangle
- turn the group to a knockout group

The text is still editable with the text tool. The method works in the same way for RGB and CMYK documents.