# Indesign: how do I clip a group by a polygon?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a group of vector objects in Indesign. Now, I want to draw a polygon and that should provide the clipping mask for the whole group. The clipping path menu-item in the object top level menu is greyed out, so I cant do anything with it. I tried to group them somehow and played with the ordering, but to no avail.

How does this work?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think Paste Into only works for raster images and not vectors. You may want to do this part in Illustrator and place the illustrator file in InDesign.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Select the objects you want clipped.
2. `Object > Group`
3. `Edit > Copy` 
   <sub>(or `Edit > Cut` - I prefer to use Copy because it's safer and easy to delete the original objects later.)</sub>
4. Select desired frame
5. `Edit > Paste Into`

To then access the frame contents, double-click it.

[image]

Works with raster or vector objects in InDesign.

The key is to **`Group`** multiple objects before copying. The `Paste Into` doesn't work if you merely select a bunch of separate objects and copy them. The copy needs to be a single object - so a group.

Comment: Thx! This app is so fucking incohaerent. I'd cant simply drag it into the layer, but I can copy it into and have it then as sublayer :D

Comment: Unlike other Adobe products, InDesign's Layers Panel is only meant for basic navigation and stacking. It's not designed for editing they way other Adobe apps use layers. InDesign is first and foremost a text and layout app, not an image editor - that's the main difference.

Comment: You know that i can drag them out of the frame in the layer window but not drag them in? This has nothing to do with the purpose of the app, this is just bad GUI style.

Answer (score 1):

There's a quite recent question of converting a piece of text to holes on a colored surface without losing the editability of the text. It's possible to copy an usable method from there. It's based on Indesign's Knockout Group.

[How can I cut out text from a plane in indesign while preserving text edit?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/161773/how-can-i-cut-out-text-from-a-plane-in-indesign-while-preserving-text-edit)

In a knockout group the top shape can define which parts of an underlying group become transparent.